# ccGridSize in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

While using ccWave, one of the parameters was `grid` and it showed that the value should be of type `ccGridSize`.

I would like to know what a `ccGridSize` is.. 
What value should be given for a `ccGridSize` variable?

The code for ccWaves is as follows...

```
[CCWaves actionWithWaves:<(int)> amplitude:<(float)>
              horizontal:<(BOOL)> vertical:<(BOOL)>
                    grid:<(ccGridSize)> duration:<(ccTime)>];
```

What value can be given in the place of the parameter grid???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `cctypes.h`:

```
 typedef struct _ccGridSize
 {
        NSInteger   x;
        NSInteger   y;
 } ccGridSize;
```

So it's just a couple of ints to state how big every step is of the grid that you are going to animate.

Comment: something like `ccGridSize gs; gs.x = 1; gs.y = 1;` and then pass `gs` or use the helper method `ccg(x,y)`

Comment: @Deepthi Use the `ccg()` function to create your `ccGridSize`, just like you do with the `ccp()` call.

Answer (score 4):

Cocos2d defines `ccGridSize` as:

```
typedef struct _ccGridSize
{
    NSInteger   x;
    NSInteger   y;
} ccGridSize;
```

And provides an inline factory function:

```
static inline ccGridSize ccg(const NSInteger x, const NSInteger y);
```

So you can write your call as:

```
... grid:ccg(gridSizeX, gridSizeY)
```

Where `gridSizeX` and `gridSizeY` define a number of grid columns and rows for your effect.